# Android Studio 0.8.2 - Gradle exception?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I just downloaded the latest version of Android studio, and now my projects no longer run.

Any idea what this exception means and how I could resolve it?

```
Error:exception during working with external system: 


Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2014-07-16 15:05:34,919 [ 625202]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home 
2014-07-16 15:05:34,920 [ 625203]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home 
2014-07-16 15:05:34,921 [ 625204]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask -  
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: 
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:211)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:116)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:406)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:483)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:380)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit dependencies in your build.gradle as :

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
}
```

Try it. It may fix your problem.

Comment: if it doesn't work, try: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.10.+'

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies says gradle:0.12. So download the 1.12 gradle from [here](http://www.gradle.org/downloads) 
and change your %GRADLE_HOME% setting